# Knex truncate table with foreign key constraints

Tags: javascript, mysql, truncate, knex.js

Is it possible to force truncate a table with foreign key constraints so that all rows in other tables effected are also removed?

I cannot see in documentation for an option to pass to `knex('tableName').truncate()` method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I haven't found a built in way to do it, so I just drop into raw mode:

```
 knex.raw('TRUNCATE TABLE users, products CASCADE')
```

You can also set this up to happen automatically in your migrations:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users_products', (t) => {
      t.uuid('id').primary().defaultTo(knex.raw('uuid_generate_v4()'));
      t.uuid('user_id').notNullable().references('id').inTable('users').onDelete('CASCADE');
      t.uuid('product_id').notNullable().references('id').inTable('products').onDelete('CASCADE');
  });
};
```

Comment: in the current version of knex, the command looks like this: `knex.schema.raw('TRUNCATE TABLE users, products CASCADE')`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work with Knex for cleaning up after Jest integration tests, so I used [Node PostGres](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) (i.e. `pg`) directly, like this:

```
  const { Pool } = require('pg')
  const connectionString = 'postgresql://dbuser:secretpassword@database.server.com:3211/mydb';
  const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString,
  })
  pool.query('TRUNCATE myTable RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;', (err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res)
    pool.end()
  })
```

Comment: Awesome answer, tried many before this worked. They key part here is was including "RESTART IDENTITY" in the raw command before "CASCADE"